# Simplest way to cycle through a bash script call

Tags: bash, cycle

I have a bash script. I would like this script to do something different every time I call it (modulus three). Something like this :

```
First script call => echo "call 1"
Second script call => echo "call 2"
Third script call => echo "call 3"
Fourth script call => echo "call 1"
Fifth script call => echo "call 2"
Sixth script call => echo "call 3"
Seventh script call => echo "call 1"
...
```

What would be the simplest way to do this ?

Note that the script is not critical. For example : the counter can go back to one after a reboot :

```
...
n script call => echo "call 1"
n+1 script call => echo "call 2"
* reboot *
n+2 script call => echo "call 1"
...
```

is OK.

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: Are concurrent calls of this script expected?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. If you mean : "the script can be called while another instance is running". The answer is : "no in a normal working case. And if there is, the cycle can be broken"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bash:

```
call=$(< call.txt)
case $call in
    0) do_thing_one;;
    1) do_thing_two;;
    2) do_thing_three;;
    *) do_oops_thing;;
esac
echo $(( (call + 1) % 3 )) > call.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest approach is probably to just store the value in a file

```
if [[ `grep 2 config.txt` ]]
then 
    #run stuff version 2
    echo 3 > config.txt # next run will be 3
elif [[ `grep 3 config.txt` ]]
then
    #run stuff version 3
    echo 1 > config.txt # next run will be 1
else
    #run stuff version 1
    echo 2 > config.txt # next run will be 2
fi
```

Comment: Why not just export an environmental variable that is unset after the third iteration?

Comment: @Tim: Because env vars only propagate down the process hierarchy, you can't modify the caller's environment.

Comment: @Tim, it could work only if the script is called with `source script.sh` or `. script.sh` i'd say a file is simpler.

Comment: It's not necessary to use command substitution (the backticks should be `$()` anyway, by the way) and brackets. You can do `if grep -qs ...` or `if grep ... > /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: @Dennis, agreed `$()` is better than backticks, habit is hard to break!